# Using AWS Cognito in .NET Desktop Application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito

AWS's Cognito service says that it is meant to be used for mobile and web platforms.

Is there any reason why it can't (or shouldn't) be used for a .NET desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Cognito, but this bit on the Getting Started page would worry me when considering a desktop application:

> To use Amazon Cognito, you must install and configure the AWS Mobile
>   SDK. For more information, see the following topics:
>
> - Set Up the AWS Mobile SDK for Android
> - Set Up the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS
> - Set Up the AWS SDK for JavaScript
> - Set Up the AWS Mobile SDK for Unity
> - Set Up the AWS Mobile SDK for Xamarin

There is no .NET SDK which means you're likely going to be playing games to get something functional for .NET (via the JS SDK or something maybe).  And I would imagine that you're also not going to receive support for that kind of environment as well.